# FileProvider crash XmlResourceParser and ProviderInfo.loadXmlMetaData on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am very new to java and android studio. Im trying to open a pdf file once it has been download on android 10 API 29. When the file link is clicked on from the webview link it downloads fine however fails to open and the app crashes with these errors from the logcat. I have a feeling my code is completely botched as its been a bit overwhelming trying to get this to work.

Here is the error in the logcat

```
Process: com.principalhomerepair.phrAdmin, PID: 20508
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser android.content.pm.ProviderInfo.loadXmlMetaData(android.content.pm.PackageManager, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.parsePathStrategy(FileProvider.java:605)
        at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.getPathStrategy(FileProvider.java:579)
        at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:417)
        at com.principalhomerepair.phrAdmin.MainActivity$6.onDownloadStart(MainActivity.java:358)
        at ic.a(PG:548)
        at An.handleMessage(PG:25)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Here is my MainActivity.java

```java
public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimeType, long contentLength) {
    if (!check_permission(2)) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, file_perm);
    } else {
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));

        //Get the name of the file being downloaded from the url
        String fileName = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);

        request.setMimeType(mimeType);
        String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
        request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookies);
        request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
        request.setDescription(getString(R.string.dl_downloading));
        request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
        DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        assert dm != null;
        dm.enqueue(request);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.dl_downloading2) + ": " + fileName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        //If the file link contains a pdf open it after downloading
        if(mimeType.contains("application/pdf")){
            File pdfFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + fileName);;

            MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
            String fileExt = pdfFile.getName().substring(pdfFile.getName().lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
            String type = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(fileExt);

            Intent openPdf_Intent = new Intent();
            openPdf_Intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                openPdf_Intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this, "com.your.package.fileProvider", pdfFile);
                openPdf_Intent.setDataAndType(contentUri, type);
            } else {
                openPdf_Intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(pdfFile), type);
            }

            startActivity(openPdf_Intent);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Viewing PDF File: " + fileName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

file_paths.xml

```xml
<?xml version ="1.0" encoding ="utf-8"?>
<paths>
<external-path name="Download" path="Download"/>
</paths>
```

AnodroidManifest.xml

```xml
<provider
    android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true"
    tools:replace="android:authorities">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
</provider>
```

UPDATED MainActivity.java

```
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimeType, long contentLength) {


            if (!check_permission(2)) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, file_perm);
            } else {
                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));

                //Get the name of the file being downloaded from the url
                String fileName = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);

                request.setMimeType(mimeType);
                String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
                request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookies);
                request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
                request.setDescription(getString(R.string.dl_downloading));
                request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
                DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                assert dm != null;
                dm.enqueue(request);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.dl_downloading2) + ": " + fileName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                //If the file link contains a pdf open it after downloading
                if(mimeType.contains("application/pdf")){

                    //Grab the file from the internal storage
                    File pdfFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/" + fileName);

                    MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
                    String fileExt = pdfFile.getName().substring(pdfFile.getName().lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
                    String type = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(fileExt);

                    Intent openPdf_Intent = new Intent("com.adobe.reader");
                    openPdf_Intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                        openPdf_Intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                        Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",pdfFile);

                        openPdf_Intent.setDataAndType(contentUri, type);
                    } else {
                        openPdf_Intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(pdfFile), type);
                    }
                    //startActivityForResult(intent, ACTIVITY_VIEW_ATTACHMENT);
                    startActivity(openPdf_Intent);

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Viewing PDF File: " + fileName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

        }
    });
```

The app no longer crashes however will not open the file in the pdf viewer. The android device says goes to the pdf viewer for a split second and then back to the app in question and thats it. It doesn't display the file

Comment: `files-path` is incorrect for your file. Technically, your hardcoded path may not work on any device and it definitely will fail on Android 10 and higher. However, `external-path` will give you better luck with your `FileProvider` metadata, at least temporarily.

Comment: @CommonsWare are you saying change the files_path.xml to external_path.xml and then reference the file like such `File pdfFile = new File(android.R.xml.external_path + fileName);`

Comment: No, I am saying change `<files-path name="Download" path="Download"/>` to `<external-path name="Download" path="Download"/>`. Sorry -- I had not noticed that you named your metadata XML resource `files_paths.xml`.

Comment: @CommonsWare I took your suggestion however it still crashed and burned however it seemed to resolve one error line being `at com.packagename.MainActivity$5.onDownloadStart(MainActivity.java:347)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line looks suspicious:

```
Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this, "com.your.package.fileProvider", pdfFile);
```

Which probably should be:

```
BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID
```

Comment: thanks. i changed it to `Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",pdfFile);`

Comment: For image, I am getting the crash

Comment: uris.add(FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "com.files.folders.manager", gadapter.getSelectedItemsFile().get(i)));

Answer (score 0):

I applied both responses from @Martin Zeitler  by changing the path tag in my xml to `<external-path name="Download" path="Download"/>` and @CommonsWare by making the change of `Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",pdfFile);`. This cleared up the issue. As far as the file not opening I came to the realization I need to check first to make sure the file has downloaded before opening which I can do with a Broadcast intent action.